# Copy and Pasting Rows into a SAS Dataset

Tags: duplicates, sas

Is there any quick and dirty way to create duplicates of an observation in a dataset?  I know I could just subset it and then use proc append, but that seems like an inelegant solution for a task that seems so simple.  Any ideas?

Comment: What's the motivation for this? Most statistical calculations that can be obtained via duplicate rows can be obtained equally well via the use of weight statements.

Answer (score 8):

I think coding it is the simplest way.

```
data work.have;
 a=1;b=2;c=3;
run;

data work.want;
 set work.have;
 output;

 if a=1 then output; /* Again */
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data check2(drop=  i );
 set check1;
 output;
  do i = 1 to datediff;
   output;
  end;
 run;
```

where there are two dates I am trying to insert number of duplicate rows
where number of rows varies and is equal to the month difference between the two dates.